# Pass Two Params From JavaScript To PHP File And ECHO Results

Tags: javascript, php

In my php file I am attempting to run a very large SQL Statement, that takes parameters of `begindate` and `enddate` - The SQL Statement has 8 CTE's and 4 of which take parameters.

The event from `onclick()` on my page fires the JavaScript to pass the variables to my php file.  My issue is that the `div` tag that should hold the variables, is empty at the end.

How should this be altered in order to succesfully return my results back to my php page?  (The query will return about 10 columns and about 500 rows when run manually in SSMS)

**HTML**

```
begin: <input type="date" name="begin" id="begin" /> 
end: <input type="date" name="end" id="end" />

<div id="results"></div>
<input type="submit" value="click" id="btn" onclick="Query()" /></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{ if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200)
{ document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhr.responseText; } }
 var begin = document.getElementById("begin").value;
 var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
 xhr.open("GET", "Help.php?begin="+begin+"&end="+end, true); 
 xhr.send();
```

And my php file reads like so (at least the beginning to show where parameters are passed in)

```
$begin = $_GET['begin'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
```

What is set-up incorrectly in my syntax that is preventing data from returning?

**EDIT**
This is the set-up of my php file

```
<?php

$begin = $_GET['begin'];
$end = $_GET['end'];

$conn = mssql_connect('Server','username','pwd') 

if ($conn===false)
{
    echo '<p>Cannot connect to SQL Server Database. Please try again later.</p>';
    exit;
}
if (mssql_select_db("DB",$conn) === false) 
{
    echo '<p>Cannot connect to DB. Please try again later.</p>';
    exit;
}
$proc = mssql_init('ProcName',$conn);
mssql_bind($proc,'@begin',$begin,SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($proc,'@end',$end,SQLVARCHAR);
if ($result = mssql_execute($proc)) 
{
    $number_of_rows = mssql_num_rows($result);
    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        echo "It Worked"
    }

    mssql_close($con);
}

?>
```

Comment: have you checked the network tab in dev console to see what the response is for your ajax call?

Comment: Check what your JavaScript variables begin and end contain. Is that the date format your PHP script expects ...?

Comment: Check the network panel to see the request and response details click the help.php request... Panel needs to be open before the call is made.

Comment: @SayantanDas - it shows a 500 internal server error

Comment: We need to see more of your PHP file if it's 500 error. Check your error_logs to see what PHP didn't like.

Comment: @NadineSmithJonesPicard Then you have issues in your php script. See what error you are getting.

Comment: @SayantanDas - see edit.

Comment: First, fix the syntax of your PHP code. There are missing `;` after `mssql_connect(...)` and after `echo "It Worked"`.

Comment: @karliwson - that did it thank you.